# MVC 5 Asp.Net Identity with multiple databases

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using MVC 5 ASP.NET Identity, which works fine when I specified the database in the connectiongString and it creates the necessary tables for me.

The problem is that the application has x numbers of databases, each database represents one customer/program. So when a user is at the login page, he will specify the program name and his credentials, and at the Login post it will have to connect to that program's database. Seems like I will need to initialize ASP.NET Identity database connection at that time and close it when done.

I am not able to find any documentation for this scenario.. any experts can help? greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could federate multiple identity providers into Azure Access Control service http://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/06/06/claims-based-federation-service-using-microsoft-azure/